# HTML background image with 100% height preserving aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get an image to fill a page using a bootstrap css template and additional custom css.

html:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cover.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="my_banner">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 ">
    <a class="btn btn-success">Ok</a>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

cover.css:

```
.my_banner {
    padding-top: 50px; 
    text-align: left;
    color: #f8f8f8;
    background: url(image.png); 
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;   
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

However the image only fills about 1/3 of height of page when browser width is small and about 1/10th of the page when browser width is made large. How can I get the entire height always filled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just need to set height to 100vh, that means you will fill all the height value of your browser

```
.my_banner{
    height: 100vh;
    background: url(image.png) center; 
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Working codepen example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rLNyvw

Answer (score 0):

you can also use background-size property fir this like:

`
.my_banner {

```
padding-top: 50px; 

text-align: left;

color: #f8f8f8;

background: url(image.png); 

background-size: 100% 100%;

background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

}`